# How to mirror a large component in Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I am using the Arduino shield pin component and I cant flip it, because it goes out of the area bounds...

Is there a way to force it to flip and then go into move mode so I can place it within the bounds? or force it to flip and then snap to the in bounds? or ? I spent 2 hours trying to get it positioned right using rotations but I really just need it mirrored and I have been unable to mirror it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EAGLE mirror command mirrors a part on its origin (or selection on its center) and moves it to the other side of the board. If the origin is not in the center the mirror will result in X or Y translation, which is causing it to go out of bounds for you.

Edit the part and move its origin to its center. Then any mirroring will not result in X or Y translation.

Addition:

To edit the part origin open the library which contains the part. Select the package editor (it's the icon with the single logic gate) and select the package of the part you wish to edit. When open, select everything, and move the layout to be centered around the origin mark in the editor screen. Save. Remember to update your libraries in your PCB layout window. The part will now mirror around its center.

Comment: thanks! I knew the origin is in the corner... but Im not sure how to change the origin.  I guess i can google it (or you could update with steps to change the origin, then this is likely the answer I would accept)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just mirroring it, can you move it, and while moving it mirror it with the middle mouse button?

Comment: For some reason, the functionality of the middle mouse button in Eagle changes for me on different computers and different platforms

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force it to flip and then go into move mode so I can place it within the bounds?

Yes. You can use the "move" command manually. If your components name is "ArduShield" type

```
move ArduShield
```

in the command prompt on below the menu bar. This will dock the component to your cursor and you can place it elsewhere.
You can also place a component at an absolute position by command.

```
move ArduShield (10 10)
```

for example.